# Is scrolling bad for Mobile? Do we need to add everything in desktop into mobile?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, html

I have this table and a submit button. So i have a large data to populate my table and that is too long for mobile where i need to scroll to see the submit button. So my client gave me a feedback that he didn't see it so he didn't know what to do. The scrollbar is visible thought but i think he really hates scrolling especially in mobile. But i need to know if scrolling is really bad for mobile?

I want my website to really become responsive which i mean i need to have only one html and javascript code for both desktop and mobile. I have this option to separate the submit button on mobile and desktop. In desktop i will retain the code while in mobile i will make another button which will stick in the screen. But i really hate the idea because i need to code it twice and it would be a problem once there are bugs and i need to fix them twice for mobile and desktop.

And also another question i have is do i have to add every functionalities that is in desktop into mobile? My web application has too many functionalities and features in desktop and it creates a problem with mobile as i have to include them all and it would make the view look overcrowded and the modernity looks off.

Anybody has any suggestions?

I am using angularjs 1x for this.

Comment: This question is way too subjective to be answerable here.

Comment: you can try bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

No, responsiveness does not demand that you don't have any scrolling bar. Its all up to you and your client's choice, if you guys are agree to keep that scrolling bar then you can go with it, but if you don't want to have then surely you have to remove it.

**Note:** In my own cases I hate scroll bars in mobile and so remove those to make it look good and every one keeping full control on the content.

Yes, you should go with `single content` and as far as your `responsiveness` concerned you can use `media queries` to solve this issue or you can use `js` to get what you want to achieve ?

Again, its all up to you, If you want to keep those functionalities then you can otherwise you can just leave those. But make sure all functional requirements are there to make your product usable. Otherwise you may get really bad reactions.

For media queries you can go in details here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Hope it makes sense and it can help you figuring out what to do now ?